# Is "torque guard" the correct translation of "Drehmomentwächter"?

Tags: technical

A *Drehmomentwächter* ist a device the gives a signal when the torque exerted by a motor is above a certain amount.

Example: A motor closes a valve, but there's a branch (or your arm!) in the way so the valve needs more force -> more torque on the motor -> *Drehmomentwächter* gives signal to turn off motor, give a larm etc.

Important distinctions are: we measure torque, not force or anything else. Binary signal in some way, either the torque is higher than X or not.

Comment: I would probably call it a "torque sensor".

Comment: sensor does not imply binary signal.

Comment: Doesn't imply that it's not.

Comment: Just for fun I tried Google Translate.  It says "torque guard".

Comment: Possibly related: see definition #5 for *governor* http://www.dictionary.com/browse/governor

Answer (score 4):

Safety switches are the general class of device. If it is electrical, it is usually called a cutout switch. If it is mechanical, usually a cutoff switch. Yours would be an overtorque safety (cutout/cutoff) switch.